# correction of recursive generator code

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator

first, thank for any help. i have this recursive code for counting ways of change from a list of coins and a given amount. i need to write a recursive generator code that presents the ways in every iteration of change money. for example if you get amount of 5 and a list of [1,2,3] coins so this will be the output:

```
for e in change_gen(5,[1,2,3]):
     print(e)

 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2]
 [1, 1, 3]
 [2, 3]
```

this what i have tried:
what's wrong?

the code using an algoritem like the binom and pascal {n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-1 \choose k}

```
def change_gen(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
       yield []
    elif not (amount < 0 or coins == []):
       g = change_gen(amount, coins[:-1])
       f = change_gen(amount - coins[:-1],coins)
       while True:
            yield Next(g)
       yield coins[:-1].extend(next2(f))
```

Comment: Where does `Next` and `next2` come from? Also note that `list.extend` returns `None`... And - does it *have* to be recursive? This is normally a problem that's quite suitable for a dynamic/constraints methodology.

Comment: next2 is wrong. and yes it is a task to write it in  recursive way. the solution should look like: def change_gen(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
       yield 
    elif not (amount < 0 or coins == []):
       g = change_gen(amount, coins[:-1])

Comment: Still doesn't explain where `Next` is coming from - you can [edit] your question to include such information and corrections

Comment: Next is to call an iteration in python

Comment: I figured that - but it doesn't have a capital `N` :) When you're asking a question try and make the actual code you're using and having issues with accurate - at the moment trying to call `Next` will be a `NameError` even though it's most likely you mean to use `next`

Comment: @AvriFridenson - Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: @zwer I was wondering why you were telling me that :p

Comment: ohh my mistake. i am very fresh in python, and in speaking english

Comment: so can you help me to fix this please? im helpless

Comment: @AvriFridenson - use `next`, notice the lowercase `n` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion is correct:  recurse both with coins reduced and with amount reduced.  Here is a corrected implementation, with test case added.

```
def change_gen(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
       yield []
    elif amount > 0 and coins:
        coin = coins.pop()
        yield from change_gen(amount, coins)
        coins.append(coin)
        for lis in change_gen(amount - coin, coins):
            lis.append(coin)
            yield lis

changes = list(change_gen(5, [1,2,3]))
print(changes)
assert changes == [
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 3],
 [2, 3],
]
```

The assertion passes.